# Math Bot keep data and sum them | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

I want to make a command that prints the number that I wrote plus the 50% of that number. For example, `!te 100` prints 150.

I did this but the problem is that I don't know how to make the command to keep all the numbers that I used with this command and when I execute the `!sum` command sum all those numbers and with the `!clear` command clear the data so I can add more numbers to sum (WARNING the numbers that I found the 50% plus the number).

Here is my code:

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.includes("!te")) {
        let ppis = message.content.substring(botprefix.length).split(" ");

        message.channel.send(((50 / 100) * parseInt(ppis[1], 10)) + parseInt(ppis[1], 10))
    }
});
```

Comment: Best option would be to use a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay to store these in memory and start with nothing on every bot restart, you can use a simple [collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) or a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to keep track of the numbers that users sent. You can use the author's ID as the key and an array of the numbers sent by them as the value:

```js
const map = new Discord.Collection();

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'boost') {
    if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0])) {
      return message.channel.send('You have to provide a number');
    }
    // add the 50%
    const amount = parseInt(args[0], 10) / 2 + parseInt(args[0], 10);

    if (map.has(message.author.id)) {
      map.set(message.author.id, [...map.get(message.author.id), amount]);
    } else {
      map.set(message.author.id, [amount]);
    }
    return message.channel.send(`\`${amount}\` added`);
  }

  if (command === 'sum') {
    if (!map.has(message.author.id))
      return message.channel.send('It seems you have no numbers yet. Maybe add some?');

    const sum = map.get(message.author.id).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    return message.channel.send(`The sum is \`${sum}\``);
  }

  if (command === 'clear') {
    const removed = map.delete(message.author.id);

    return message.channel.send(
      removed
        ? 'Numbers are cleared'
        : 'It seems you have no numbers yet. Maybe add some?',
    );
  }
});
```

[image]